# Integral form of work during an irreversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, integration, reversibility, non-equilibrium

### Question

Why can't the work during an irreversible process be integrated? Where is my understanding amiss?

### Motivation (for this question)

A lot of my physics background seems to say this is a math problem. My understanding of the problem can be summarised by:

[image] 
-[lecture slide](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~gja/thermo/lectures/lecture2.pdf)

where $P$ is pressure, $V$ is volume and $T$ is temperature.

### My counter solution

Do not consider the "system" as one system in total. But consider the "system" as the aggregate of infinitesimal subsystems. Each with their own $P$,$V$,$T$. One should be able to use the [first law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-equilibrium_thermodynamics#Flows_and_forces)   and construct an integral form of work using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3359525/430082).

Comment: This subdivision technique is antithetical to the philosophy of classical thermodynamics. It's also not totally apparent whether it works in reality, this hinges on quantum mechanical issues that are still unresolved today.

Comment: In any case what is going on is "morally" like what you say: in an irreversible process the solution moves through a manifold that is "really" higher dimensional than the equilibrium thermodynamic manifold, so that in principle the work can be calculated by integrating a line integral on this higher dimensional manifold. But what are the other dimensions? How do you select them? This is a problem of non-equilibrium dimension reduction and it is usually quite difficult.

Comment: @Ian My understanding is Noether's theorem of time translation symmetry should hold even if as an average of a quantity?  By this logic, one can "cheat" and get empirical approximate solutions (the answer linked "this" uses something in the spirit of riemann sums) or one can start micro(-if-possible) and scale it up?

Comment: A serious problem with starting micro is that it isn't clear how the second law comes out.

Comment: @Ian I do have non-mainstream opinions about that. So I'd rather go the empirical route to micro if that's okay?

Comment: Anyway the thermodynamic way to do this involves examining the process and finding some small set of augmented variables which change during the process while the other variables oscillate in an equilibrated fashion. For example if you suddenly move a piston then perhaps you can divide the gas chamber into compartments with well-defined pressure (possibly moving the compartments with the motion of the pressure wave) and then treat that enlarged system as being at equilibrium during the dynamics. Working with a $10^{23}$ dimensional phase space is not reasonable for modeling.

Comment: @Ian I guess one could argue my route is not thermodynamics then? Atleast "Morally". I think it might be possible (maybe I'm overoptimistic?) One should be able to use this to study a mesoscopic object?

Comment: Basically this kind of decomposition is just working with microscopic physics directly rather than thermodynamics. It can be done in principle but in some sense thermodynamics as we understand it now exists to achieve dimension reduction in this kind of system because computing anything on such a high dimensional problem is simply impossible. (Note however that thermodynamics is older than molecular theory...)

Comment: You are talking about infinitesimal subsystems. Sooner or later your subsystem only really has one molecule in it, so it only makes sense to resolve things to that scale. You can divide things up a finite amount, in which case what you are doing is along the lines of what I said, depending on how far you go with it. But the main point is just that too much subdivision of a large system makes computation impossible, which makes it impossible to make testable predictions. Trying to resolve things beyond this scale moves more into physical philosophy than physical science.

Comment: @Ian I was making a point referring to "A serious problem with starting micro is that it isn't clear how the second law comes out." And letting you know about my views (subliminally) as opposed to "I do have non-mainstream opinions ... " :) Anyway feel free to write an answer for the question?

Comment: I am not so sure there really is a satisfactory mathematical answer to your question; I would be more comfortable writing an answer to this question on Physics SE because the answer doesn't really have anything to do with actual math. It's a matter of philosophy of mathematical modeling essentially.

Comment: @Ian relevant: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12528/

Comment: @Ian Please do answer now? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/515541/integral-form-of-work-during-an-irreversible-process/515559#515559

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Pi$ is the force per unit area exerted by the gas on the face of the piston during an irreversible expansion or compression, then $\int{\Pi dV}$ is indeed the work done by the gas on its surroundings (i.e., the piston).  The problem is that $\Pi$ is not equal to the pressure calculated from the ideal gas law ($P=\frac{nRT}{V}$) because the ideal gas law only applies under a state of thermodynamic equilibrium, and the states experienced by a gas during an irreversible expansion or compression are not thermodynamics equilibrium states.  In an irreversible expansion or compression, because of viscous deformational effects, the force per unit area depends not only on the gas volume but also on the rate of change of gas volume.  So the equation of state cannot be applied to calculate the work.  However, if the piston is massless and the force per unit area of the piston is imposed externally (i.e., controlled manually), then, by Newton's 3d law of motion, $\Pi = P_{ext}$, and the work can be calculated as $\int{P_{ext}dV}$.

In the case of a *reversible process*, the gas passes through continuous sequence of thermodynamic equilibrium state, and thus, the ideal gas law can be used to calculate the force per unit area exerted by the gas on the piston:  $$\Pi=P=\frac{nRT}{V}$$ and the work is $$\int{\Pi dV}=\int{\frac{nRT}{V}dV}$$

ADDENDUM

In an irreversible process, the force per unit area at the boundary of your system (as determined, in an irreversible process, by the Newtonian fluid stress tensor) and the rate of heat transfer from the surroundings to the system (as determined by the heat flux vector) are functions of position on the boundary separating the system from its surroundings.  These both vary with position on the boundary.  So you need to integrate over the boundary area the stress tensor dotted with a unit normal and with the boundary velocity vector to get the rate of doing work, and you need to integrate over the boundary area the heat flux vector dotted with the unit normal to get the rate of heat transfer.  You then have to integrate these with respect to time.  It is not enough to integrate the pressure times velocity over the boundary area, since the pressure is only part of the Newtonian stress tensor (the true force per unit area), and does not include viscous contributions to the stress.

Moreover, to get the stress tensor and the heat flux at the boundary in an irreversible process, you need to solve the Navier Stokes fluid dynamic equations in conjunction with the partial differential thermal energy balance equation (which involves the stress tensor), and the partial differential (mass conservation) continuity equation throughout the domain of the system.

If you want to learn more about all this, please see Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.

Comment: I think the first law of thermodyamics can be extended to non-equilibrium cases as well (see wiki link: "the first law of thermodynamics").

Comment: I agree that it can be done locally, provided the isotropic pressure tensor is replaced by the by the Newtonian fluid stress tensor.  For the details of how this works, see Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.

Comment: I think the link "this" enables one to talk about this globally (as an integral) as well?

Comment: If it is expressed as an integral, you still need to know the integrand locally, so you still have to solve for what is happening inside.

Comment: One can go macro to micro (using empircal means) or micro to macro by knowing the integrand locally using means such as "the "system" as the aggregate of infinitesimal subsystems. Each with their own ,,  ." (I think we might be in agreement?)

Comment: I disagree.  You can’t use P locally.

Comment: I am going to add an ADDENDUM to indicate what you really need to do.

Comment: +1. Anyway, don't you think that, even if the the stress tensor with Navier-Stokes and related equations capture some irreversible fenomena, there is still a whole lot of irreversible fenomena not described by them? Those involving turbulence, for example.

Comment: @HicHaecHoc No, not really.  The Navier Stokes and the other equations are consistent with turbulence being present.  We just don't know how to solve them yet when turbulence is present.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand (correct me if I am wrong), the problem is more physical than mathematical, a reversible process is something which we can represent using curves in planes just like in Calculus and that's where the Math starts and also stops.

What's happening with a reversible process is that the work or heat transfer during the process has caused the system to take a particular path and assume its states and hence we use integration formulas like $W = \int pdV $ or $Q = \int Tds $ and so on.
But for an irreversible process, there is no link between the work (or heat) and the states of the system. The end states are totally unrelated to the energy transfer (if you try to fit a process it will a reversible one!) and the intermediate states are unpredictable (theoretically and experimentally: remember you cannot reproduce an irreversible process, then how can you make any observation!?)

So instead what is done is even an irreversible process is represented as a reversible process on the graph and later correction terms are added to indicate irreversibility.

On a side note: Thermodynamics totally ignores irreversibility in processes and carries on assuming everything as ideal, perfect and reversible.

Comment: Can you please add some references? "there is no link between the work (or heat) and the states of the system" seems to suggest the first law (conservation of energy) is violated ? One does use inexact differentials to express this law as well: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/Energies_and_Potentials/Differential_Forms_of_Fundamental_Equations

Comment: "remember you cannot reproduce an irreversible process, then how can you make any observation" - I disagree Noether's theorem of time translational symmetry should hold even if as an average :)

Comment: @MoreAnonymous, Q and W are inexact unless you are working with a gradient field, reversibility and irreversibility have got nothing to do with it.... states of a system and transfers are related in a reversible process.... they are not related in an irreversible process doesn't mean its a violation of First Law, remember after all it is a law of energy balance.

Comment: W = -PdV is for an isobaric reversible process but for an irreversible process between the same states: W > -PdV because some energy was expended in friction etc.

Comment: "they are not related in an irreversible process doesn't mean its a violation of First Law" ... I'm slightly confused by this statement. One can start from the equations of motions and end with the symmetries of physics. Equally one can start with symmetries and go to equations of motions. The procedure (noether's theorem) makes it seem one will also end up with a time symmetric PDE.

Comment: "because some energy was expended in friction " - I should be able to take friction into account empirically by adding knowledge of the coefficient of friction.

Comment: Also I accidentally deleted a comment. Not sure how to get it back :/

Comment: In the scope of classical thermodynamics, no! but if you are building a generalized approach there are many empirical formulations available even in classical physic. Why empirical? because the coefficients one is looking to account for heat and work dissipation are too damn complex for being highly multivariate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101389/discussion-between-more-anonymous-and-dubsveer23).